# OpenGL ES (on iOS):

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a series of standard OpenGL instructions in this form:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
// ...
glNormal3fv(a); glVertex3f(a[0]*r, a[1]*r, a[2]*r);
// ...
glEnd();
```

I wish to run them on iOS, thus must convert them to OpenGL ES. Since OpenGL ES doesn't support glBegin() or glEnd(), I'm wrapping up the glVertex3f calls into a GLfloat vertices array followed by a glDrawArrays() call instead.

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {1,0,0, 0,1,0, ...};
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

However I'm unsure how to include the specification of a normal vector (the original glNormal3fv() calls) in this ES version.

Would someone be kind enough to exemplify the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `glNormalPointer()`.  It works in much the same way as `glVertexPointer()`, but with fewer options since normals always have 3 floating point components.

Comment: I very much appreciate your quick reply, thanks Drew. So in fact all that's needed here is another line before the glDrawArrays() call with: glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

Comment: @KomodoDave:  That should do it!

Comment: I made a slight slip-up here - I do in fact need a separate 'normals' array since the normal is 'a' vs the vertex a*r (see original code). Anyway, all sorted now I think, am about to test.. thanks :)

Comment: @KomodoDave:  Sorry--I should have seen that in your comment before.  Hope it worked for you...

Comment: No problem - I should have realised immediately myself! I've finished the related OGLES code but am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS sadly - I've posted a separate issue elsewhere, feel free to comment if you've any idea of the problem, no worries if not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807189/opengl-es-on-ios-exc-bad-access-on-gldrawarrays-call-for-sphere-drawing